# Trap array changes (add/delete) inside object of proxy

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, es6-proxy

I am trying to track some array changes inside of proxyfied object.
For example:

```
object = { 
    count: 0, 
    input: ``, 
    tasks: [ ] 
}
```

and I need to track changes of `object.tasks`.

The problem is that proxy catches all changes (set, get etc.) related to object, and even array (`object.tasks`) sets (means event 'set' fires and traps array changes, but not removes (delete) like `delete object.tasks[someIndex]`, or changes like `array.filter((x, index) => index !== some)` and so on.

So my question is: what's the proper way to trap this changes?

upd:

```
const createElement = (any) => {
    const { tagName = undefined, className = '', id = undefined, state = { }, render = undefined, ...some } = any
    const element = tagName ? document.createElement(tagName) : document.createDocumentFragment()
    if(tagName){
        if(className) element.className = className
        if(id) element.id = id
    }
    if(render){
        if(state){
            element.state = new Proxy(state, {
                deleteProperty(entry, v){
                    console.log(entry, v)
                    delete(entry[v])
                    return true
                },
                set(entry, k, v){
                    if(entry[k] !== v){
                        console.log(entry, v)
                        entry[k] = v
                        const children = render({ state: entry })
                        element.childNodes.forEach((child, i) => {
                            if(typeof(children[i]) === 'string' || typeof(children[i]) === 'number') children[i] = document.createTextNode(children[i])
                            !children[i].isEqualNode(child) && element.replaceChild(children[i], child) && console.log('Element updated: ', children[i])
                        })
                    } else {
                        console.log(k, v)
                    }
                    return true
                }
            })
        }
        const children = render({ state: element.state })
        if(typeof(children) === 'object' && children instanceof(Array)) element.replaceChildren(...children)
        else element.replaceChildren(children)
    }
    if(some){
        Object.assign(element, some)
    }
    return element
}

document.querySelector('#root').replaceChildren(
    createElement({ tagName: 'div', className: 'class-test',
        render: () => ([
            `buttons test (dec/inc)`,
            createElement({ tagName: 'div', state: { count: 0 },
                render: ({ state }) => [
                    createElement({ tagName: 'button', className: 'btn-decrease',
                        onclick: () => state.count--,
                        render: () => `-`
                    }),
                    `Clicked ${ state.count } times...`,
                    createElement({ tagName: 'button', className: 'btn-increase',
                        onclick: () => state.count++,
                        render: () => `+`
                    })
                ]
            }),
            `inputs test (tasks, click on task to remove)`,
            createElement({ tagName: 'form', state: { input: ``, tasks: [ ] },
                onsubmit: (e) => {
                    e.preventDefault()
                    e.target.reset()
                },
                render: ({ state }) => [
                    createElement({ tagName: `ul`,
                        render: () => state.tasks.map((task, i) => createElement({
                            tagName: 'li',
                            onclick: () => delete state.tasks[i],
                            render: () => task
                        }))
                    }),
                    createElement({ tagName: 'input', placeholder: `Text some task..`,
                        oninput: ({ target }) => state.input = target.value
                    }),
                    createElement({ tagName: 'button', type: 'submit',
                        onclick: () => state.input ? state.tasks.push(state.input) && (state.input = ``) : null,
                        render: () => `Set task`
                    })
                ]
            })
        ])
    })
)
```

Comment: You need a proxy for the array itself. Changing the array doesn't do anything to the object that references it.

Comment: *"or changes like array.filter((x, index) => index !== some)"*: that's not a change.

Comment: @trincot I was mean array = array.filter(...)

Comment: That just assigns a new array to an `array` variable, and will not change the array being referenced by your (proxied) object.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your reply. Thats the point actually, that im trying to avoid (potentualy) unnecessary proxyfying properties inside of object, even if property is array. I just dont actually get it why i can track array pushes but not filters/deletes. Ofcourse we can afford it to create a proxy in proxy etc to track everything we need in envs like node, but any changes or additional proxies affects the DOM. So thats why this question was asked.

Comment: `object.tasks.push()` shouldn't be tracked. But `object.tasks =` will be tracked by the proxy.

Comment: Please post a [mre] showing what you tried.

Comment: @Barmar I've updated initial question post. Please check this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an example that shows that it tracks pushes? Because I don't think it should.

Comment: @Barmar https://jsfiddle.net/7apx1gcs/1/

Comment: @Barmar so when i push task (to state) - whole ul rerenders (and thats fine btw or maybe not), but when i am clicking to task that was just created - nothing happens, but the same array changes,  was trying to catch any possible events in proxy handler - nothing fires and the ony push events makes <ul> rerenders.

Comment: I added `console.log` calls before and after `state.tasks.push(state.input)`. None of the logs in the proxy showed between these, so it's not triggering anything.

Comment: @Barmar now i got it. After state.tasks.push(state.input) i was calling  && (state.input = ``) so that properly affects proxy changes. Now i got it. Thank you so much!